# Spam posts by bots and dealing with them

Tags: feature-request, spam

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286060/ways-create-muscle-fast-quick-tips-to-put-on-muscle) URL ("Ways Create Muscle Fast - Quick Tips To Put On Muscle" on Arqade ...) might work for the higher tier users, but should be deleted by the time this question goes live. Many such "questions" are posted by bots daily all over Stack Exchange. And they don't seem to be slowing down.

Even though it got deleted in about a minute, it's still annoying to see the tab blinking with a new notification only to find this c*ap.

I feel like a one-time question verification review before it actually goes visible would solve the spam issue.

The reviews tend to be completed quite quickly (literally seconds) so it wouldn't hurt the asker much.

1. If the user is legit then this(their first question - requiring review)
   and any other questions would get posted instantly no questions
   asked. Should the user have a later question deleted (not just
   closed) then the "Requires admin to allow this question on the site"
   flag would turn on again.
2. If the user is a bot and/or simply posts a spam question "Why viagra is good for the body, find out here" then the question never sees daylight and the user is deleted from the network. Even if the question is completely off-topic, if it's an actual question it'd get moved/closed and not deleted so the legit user is at no risk even here.

**This would only happen for the first question of a newly created user with no questions.**

Comment: Maybe it should not be done for all new posts, but only for those that are identified as "possible spam".

Comment: On small sites, reviews sometimes take hours, even days.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This type of "a priori" filtering should only be on high-traffic sites. I think Arqade qualifies.

Answer (score 5):

In the way you propose it, this will probably be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).
Stack Exchange wants people to be able to post questions and have eyes on them quickly. The quick response time, in combination with the high signal-to-noise ratio, has always been what attracted askers to SE.

However, the idea isn't bad. Stack Exchange already has a lot of spam fighting behind the scenes, or so we're told. On top of that, we have the [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) chatbot which has an excellent track record in finding spam that evaded the filters.

Combine these two systems, and you have a system for identifying "spam candidates"; posts that the system believes to be spam but isn't certain enough. These would be placed in this new "possible spam" queue.

I normally oppose review queues, because we have a lot of robo-reviewers. In this case, I think a review queue could work. Spam identification isn't difficult. As an added benefit, a special queue for "possible spam" would help us identify robo-reviewers quickly.

This queue should only be available on the sites that have enough traffic for a post to be reviewed quickly, like Stack Overflow or Ask Ubuntu. For low-traffic sites, I'd prefer judgement of posts after they're on the front page. To prevent innocent users from having to wait for hours before their post appears.

Comment: "Combine these two systems..." This idea is being worked on. I'm not sure how much I can say without committing SE to anything, but the Charcoal team (the people behind Smokey) and the SE team are looking into ways of integrating the systems.

Comment: To be fair, on "arqade" and "the workplace", which combine 82k questions have spam deleted in a minute or less. But I can see where you're coming from

Comment: @ИвоНедев Average time to deletion across the network is actually on the order of 5-10 minutes; see the bottom graph on [this page](https://m.erwaysoftware.com/graphs). We're trying to work in some per-site stats.

Comment: The time to deletion for the reported post was [3 minutes](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/41019)

Comment: I believe the "special queue" is currently the review audit system, which does specifically address robo-reviewers (or just anyone not paying attention).